# Get a row based on data from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables:

```
dialogs:
id
```

and

```
users_dialogs:
user_id
dialog_id
```

How can I get (SELECT FROM ...) a dialog ID by two user IDs? Example:

```
dialogs:
id: 1
```

```
users_dialogs:
user_id: 2 | dialog_id: 1
user_id: 7 | dialog_id: 1
```

need return dialog with id = 1... idk how

Comment: Its not completely clear what you are asking here!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have two rows in the 'users_dialogs' table that have the same 'dialog_id'. I need to get it id (in one select-query) so that later I can get data from another table (dialogs)

Comment: SO do you know which dialog_id you want to get the `user_id` for? So you can add a where clause to the query? Or do you want ALL the user_id's for all the dialog_id's

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need to find a common dialog_id for two different user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gets the user_ids and the dialog_ids from `users_dialogs` where the dialog_id exists in the `dialogs` table.

```
SELECT user_id, dialog_id FROM users_dialogs WHERE user_id IN (2,7)
```

Gives

```
users_dialogs:
user_id: 2 | dialog_id: 1
user_id: 7 | dialog_id: 1
```

You need to fill the user_ids programmatically in your code

Comment: I have to find an unknown common 'dialog_id' for two known 'user_id'

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by that? You want to get the 'dialog_id' where the user_id = 2 or 7? What values are known to you?

Comment: "You want to get the 'dialog_id' where the user_id = 2 or 7?" - yes. I know user_id's.

Comment: Updated my answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, I edited it for myself, and it turned out like this: `SELECT d1.id FROM site.dialogs d1 JOIN site.users_dialogs d2 ON d1.id = d2.dialog_id WHERE d1.type = 'personal' AND d2.user_id IN (2,7) LIMIT 1`